# How to have the number and the caption of a figure in Word showing in one line?

Tags: ms-word

Using APA style, I have the figure number and the figure caption in two different lines.
For example

[image]

When I use `Insert Table of Figure` on the `References` tab, I get a table that only captures the figure number. For example, it shows as:

Figure 2.............15

What I want to achieve is
Figure 2: Framework for Sequential Exploratory Mixed Methods.....15

[15 is the page number]
I also have all my tables and Appendix in the double-line format. I need to get the same results for them too.

How to achieve this in Microsoft Word?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. Before you ask, you may want to look at http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesKenyon, I will remove this post from here. Thanks for suggesting the alternatives.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, your post is well-written. Even though it may not seem relevant to a Table of Figures, do look at the article I linked. The TOF uses the TOC field.